# smarty v2 loop else does not pickup variable

Tags: smarty

Why does in the {elseif} part the variable not get displayed?

```
{section name="images" start="1" loop=$smarty.const.MAX_EXTRA_IMAGES+1}
{assign var="ind" value=$smarty.section.images.index}
{if $output.prodRow.images[$ind].image_nr}
<li>A:{$output.prodRow.images[$ind].cover_img}      // returns foo
{elseif !$output.prodRow.images[$ind].image_nr}
<li>B:{$output.prodRow.images[$ind].cover_img}  // returns nothing
{/if}
</div>
{/section}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean "return nothing" but it works as intended because if image_nr is not set probably you don't have set any cover_img:

When in PHP file you have:

```
$output['prodRow']['images'][1]['image_nr'] = 1;
$output['prodRow']['images'][1]['cover_img'] = 'foo';

$smarty->assign('output', $output);

error_reporting(0);
$smarty->display('elseif.tpl');
```

And in template file you have:

```
{section name="images" start="1" loop=5}
{assign var=ind value=$smarty.section.images.index}
{if $output.prodRow.images[$ind].image_nr}
<li>A:{$output.prodRow.images[$ind].cover_img}      
{elseif !$output.prodRow.images[$ind].image_nr}
<li>B:{$output.prodRow.images[$ind].cover_img}  
{/if}
{/section}
```

The output is:

```
A:foo
B:
B:
B:
```

as expected.

And when you have in your PHP file:

```
$output['prodRow']['images'][1]['image_nr'] = 1;
$output['prodRow']['images'][1]['cover_img'] = 'foo';
$output['prodRow']['images'][2]['cover_img'] = 'foo2';

$smarty->assign('output', $output);

error_reporting(0);
$smarty->display('elseif.tpl');
```

And don't change anything in your template file, output is:

```
A:foo
B:foo2
B:
B:
```

as expected.

So answering your question you probably don't set cover_img if image_nr is not set in your PHP script.